# Disable button after ajax Success

Tags: magento

I need to disalble submit button after ajax forever!
But when I reload the page submit button is active(

```
function submitConfirmAjaxList(e){
    var url = "<?php echo $this->getUrl('wedding/gifts/confirmList') ?>";
    var getTransferId = '<?php echo $checkTransferId?>';
    var getCurrentCustomerId = '<?php echo $getCurrentCustomerId?>';
    var confirmResponse = 1;
    var disalleButton = $('confirmButton').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');

    new Ajax.Request(url, {
        method:'post',
        parameters: {
            getTransferId : getTransferId,
            getCurrentCustomerId : getCurrentCustomerId,
            confirmResponse : confirmResponse
        },
        requestHeaders: {Accept: 'application/json'},
        onSuccess: function(transport) {
            location.reload();
            e.disable();

        }
    });

}
```

__('Сonfirm the list')?>" class="button" onclick="submitConfirmAjaxList(this)">__('confirm the list')?>

Comment: `onSuccess: function(transport) { location.reload();` - the point of Ajax is to let you do things involving the server without loading a new page. Why are you bothering to use Ajax at all if you reload the page as soon as the request is made?

Comment: reload for checking. I`ll delete it.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily accomplish that if you would delete your `location.reload();`. The idea of ajax is the asynch call, which is executed and processed **without** reloading the entire page. That said you can just put `$('#confirmButton').attr('disabled', 'disabled');` in your `onSuccess: function(transport) {}` method and you should be fine

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$('#button_id').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Comment: And i need to do this in prototype or js

Answer (score 0):

If you reload the page then you have a new page which doesn't maintain state from any previous changes you made with JavaScript.

You need to store something on the server (e.g. in session data or the user's account data in the database) that indicates the submit button should be disabled.

Then your server side code should include a `disabled` attribute in the button when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

After sucess, put some value in cookie, validaty of cookie should be till current session, on page load (may be document.ready) check if cookie value is specific to which you stored then disable the button with jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in AJAX Success:

$(".class").attr('disabled','disabled');